# Ajax NumericUpDownExtender error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, numericupdown

I am getting this error when trying to use the numericupdown control:

> Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30512.20315,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' contains a Web
>   resource with name
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.NumericUpDown.NumericUpDownBehavior.debug.js', but
>   does not contain an embedded resource with name
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.NumericUpDown.NumericUpDownBehavior.debug.js'.

I have researched this and have found that this problem arises because the source code for the AJAXToolkit calls the file 'NumericUpDownBehavior.debug..js'. The only solution I have seen is this one:

> Download the ajax control toolkit with the source code. Go to the folder
>   "AjaxControlToolkit\NumericUpDown\" and there's a file there named
>   "NumericUpDownBehavior.debug..js". Rename it to "NumericUpDownBehavior.debug.js".
>   After this open the "AjaxControlToolkt" project in Visual studio and choose "Show All
>   Files" in Solution Explorer". Exclude from the project the file with
>   the double dots (.debug..js) and include the correct one. Right click
>   on the .js file and choose "Properties". From there Choose the Build
>   Action "Embedded Resource". Compile it and add the resulting dll to to
>   your projects where you are using ajax (Replace the dll's).

I have tried this but I must have done it wrong because it did not work. Can anyone provide a more detailed solution to this problem?

Thanks!